# Execute MySQL Delete on Button Click

Tags: php, mysql, database

In my code, I am showing a table within my database called staff in a HTML table and I want to add a delete button to each row in the HTML table that when clicked, it will delete the record its associated with.

Based on searching other solutions, my code looks like this:

staff.php:

```
require_once('../connection.php');

          //delete row on button click
          if(isset($_GET["del"])){
                    $idc = $_GET["del"];
                    if($VisitorManagement->query("DELETE FROM staff WHERE id=$idc")){
                         header('Location: delete-thankyou.php');
                    } else { 
                        echo "Failed to delete staff member.";
                    }    
                }  

            $result = mysqli_query($VisitorManagement, "SELECT * FROM staff ORDER BY fullName");

            echo "<table id='staff'>
            <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>";



            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {   
                echo "<tbody>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['fullName'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td><a class='button alert' href='staff.php?del=".$row["idc"]."'>Delete</a></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
         echo "</tbody>";   
         echo "</table>";
```

connection.php:

```
$hostname_VisitorManagement = "localhost";
$database_VisitorManagement = "visitor-management";
$username_VisitorManagement = "***";
$password_VisitorManagement = "***";
$VisitorManagement = mysqli_connect($hostname_VisitorManagement, $username_VisitorManagement, $password_VisitorManagement, $database_VisitorManagement);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

Unfortunately, when I go to the click one of the buttons, it fails to delete the record and echoes the error message pre-defined in staff.php. Am I missing something to get this to work?

Comment: You should post the error message you're getting to make it a bit easier for us.

Comment: @ExoSkeleton321 It only shows the "Failed to delete staff member" error message I pre-defined in my staff.php code

Comment: i have run the code and it works on my computers.

Comment: are you sure that this is $row["idc"] and not $row["id"]? :)

Comment: You should try obtaining the actual error message with `catch(Exception $e){ echo "error: ".$e->getMessage();}`. Try that and let us know what the error is saying.

Comment: @Webeng he already shows us the error. echo "Failed to delete staff member.";

Comment: @LorenceHernandez I don't know how it helped, but changing all instances of idc to id fixed the issue.

Comment: @LorenceHernandez I assumed that him saying `"Failed to delete staff member" error message I pre-defined in my staff.php code` means he used a `try{}catch{}` exception block but personalized the message to just say "failed to delete staff" in which case he could of obtained the actual error message thrown by the function that failed if he used `$e->getMessage();`

Comment: @NicoleFoster nope, you just need to change the row["idc"] to row["id"]. it has nothing to do with your $idc. you were passing row["idc"] (which i think doesnt exist in your table or atleast has different value you are expecting) to del. and then when you execute this query "DELETE FROM staff WHERE id=$idc" it cant find the value of del in the table so the query returns false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by changing all instances of idc to id.

New code is:

```
require_once('../connection.php');

      //delete row on button click
      if(isset($_GET["del"])){
                $id = $_GET["del"];
                if($VisitorManagement->query("DELETE FROM staff WHERE id=$id")){
                     header('Location: delete-thankyou.php');
                } else { 
                    echo "Failed to delete staff member.";
                }    
            }  

        $result = mysqli_query($VisitorManagement, "SELECT * FROM staff ORDER BY fullName");

        echo "<table id='staff'>
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>";



        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {   
            echo "<tbody>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['fullName'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td><a class='button alert' href='staff.php?del=".$row["id"]."'>Delete</a></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
     echo "</tbody>";   
     echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Couple of security recommendations: use parameterised queries to protect against SQL injection. If you use a GET request to delete a record then browser prefetching and browser based link checkers will delete any visible records. When you use POST for delete, don't forget CSRF protection.